# Visual SourceSafe 2005 - How to GET changed files for a certain date range (command line tool)

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe

Here I was trying to perform a GET operation to pull a list of files that have been checked in/changed for a given date range, excluding the ones that have not been changed in that time frame.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ss Get $\MY_PROJECT to . -Vd8/01/10;12:00a~08/03/10;11:59p -R
```

In the beginning it actually seems to do what I want - it keeps crunching for a while trying to figure out the files that have changed. Then, all of a sudden, it dumps the remaining non-changed files in the same dir.

Is there a way to achieve what I need? If yes, what's missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (my vss is on a remote server):

SET SSDIR=\$myserver\myvss\myproject

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\SS.exe" history $/myproject -Vd31/12/10~17/11/10 -R

Please note that the end date is BEFORE the start date in the range.

I only needed a list of what changes and not the files, that's why I used history.